# Need a hint to be able to add data from a textbox in a form to a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC 5. I need some hints how to add input data from a form in a View to a List? When I click on the submit button, I want to add the name from the textbox to a list of strings. After I have called the page, I'm going to show a list of names below the form inlcuding the last entered name in the textbox. Hints or some guidance are appreciated.

I have this model:

```
namespace MVC_1.Models
{
public class NameModel
{
    public static List<string> nameList;

    public string name { get; set;}
}
}
```

But where should I create an instance of the of the list? Should that be in the Controller and should I also have some kind of method in the controller that add the the input to the list? I think it's not the correct way since I create a new instance every time I click on the submit button.

In the Controller I return an instance of the list to be able to make a razor loop of the list.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NameInput(string inValue)
    {
        // Create an instance of class ListNamesModel
        var listNames = new MVC_1.Models.NameModel();

        //listNames.name = inValue;

        return View(listNames);
    }
```

Comment: Your question is an opinion based and there are many answers depending on a context. You could check what Microsoft [suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404093.aspx). I would say that if your logic is really easy then you could put it in the model. If you know that the logic behind will be complicated - create a separate business layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your list directly with the declaration:
public static List nameList = new List();

Since you declared it static there will be just one and it will be created once only. You may want to check for doubles before adding and clear the list at some point.